# Could not find server 'STLEDGSQL01' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

The following SQL script is what I'm trying to execute using SQL Server Management Studio to get my end result and one of the stackoverflow member answered this script as per my needs, so I'm assuming the script is correct. But the issue is when I execute the script it gives me the following error.

Script

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    RTRIM(trx_date), RTRIM(work_order), RTRIM(department), 
    RTRIM(work_center), RTRIM(operation_no), RTRIM(operator), 
    RTRIM(total_labor_hours), RTRIM(feet_produced),
    RTRIM(item_no), RTRIM(lot_no), RTRIM(default_bin), RTRIM(posted) 
FROM 
    NOR_LABOR
WHERE 
    ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID)
           FROM [STLEDGSQL01].[MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] 
           WHERE work_center LIKE ('%NOR%'))
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

Error

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'STLEDGSQL01' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers.
```

I have tried to execute that statement in many different ways since my colleagues advised me adding the 'SERVER' and 'DATABASE' might be little extraneous but still keep getting errors as below

1. Keeping all the source and destination server/database/table name.

```
SELECT * FROM [Normac Data].[dbo].[NOR_LABOR] WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM [STLEDGSQL01].[MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'STLEDGSQL01' in sysservers. Execute sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sysservers.
```

2. Removing the destination 'server' only and keeping everything else same.

```
SELECT * FROM [Normac Data].[dbo].[NOR_LABOR] WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM [MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'MES_DEV.dbo.ALL_LABOR_DETAILS'.
```

3. Removing the destination 'server' and 'database' only and keeping everything else same.

```
SELECT * FROM [Normac Data].[dbo].[NOR_LABOR] WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM [dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS] WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'dbo.ALL_LABOR_DETAILS'.
```

4. Removing the destination 'server' and 'database' and 'dbo' only and keeping everything else same.

```
SELECT * FROM [Normac Data].[dbo].[NOR_LABOR] WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM ALL_LABOR_DETAILS WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid object name 'ALL_LABOR_DETAILS'.
```

5. Removing the source server only and keeping everything else same.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NOR_LABOR] WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM ALL_LABOR_DETAILS WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid object name 'ALL_LABOR_DETAILS'.
```

6. Removing the source server and database only and keeping everything else same.

```
SELECT * FROM NOR_LABOR WHERE ID > (SELECT MAX(SOURCE_ID) FROM ALL_LABOR_DETAILS WHERE work_center LIKE '%NOR%') ORDER BY ID

Error : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid object name 'ALL_LABOR_DETAILS'.
```

I tried everything that I know but still not working, what else can I do to make this query work? Thank you all!

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here, it's telling you the problem. You are trying to reference the linked server `STLEDGSQL01` and clearly it doesn't exists on the instance you are connected to. You need to create the linked server on  the instance if you want to be able to reference it.

Comment: You connect to what sql server instance and database to access the table NOR_LABOR? And where, in relation to this instance and database is the table ALL_LABOR_DETAILS? No one but you (and apparently not your colleagues either) knows anything about your various databases and instances. If you don't know, then stop writing code and go look for the tables you need. Ask more people in your own organization.

Comment: Do you guys know any way to bypass that creating a linked server by using a JOIN or something in the query? Like a way that I can change the query but not changing any settings in server/database side in SSMS? If not I was thinking to make the query to 2 different parts like run the first query which is to get the maximum ID and store in a variable. Use that variable's value as the where clause?